# 3G module how to get signal strength after ppp connection?

Tags: embedded

i am using a forlinx ok6410 board and 3G module
how to get signal strength for a Forlinx 3G module after ppp connection?
It could be achieved by the AT(AT+CSQ)command, but AT could not be send out after the ppp connection, so how to get the signal strength?

Answer (score 3):

Not sure about your particular device, but in general with modem AT command set devices you can enter command mode while maintaining the connnection by sending the sequence:

> <1 second pause>+++<1 second pause>

Then data mode can be reentered with the ATO command (that's A-T-Oh, not A-T-Zero).

Comment: how do you do this from within a PPP connection? ppp seems to only provide connection and disconnection 'chat' scripts.

Comment: @MarkLakata: The pause+++pause sequence is detected by the modem and places it into command mode - it is not forwarded to the link. PPP is not relevant - that is about end-to-end connection establishment and occurs over the link with the remote modem. The question is about *after* the connection is established.  See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hayes_command_set) - search in page for "+++" to find the description.  The "guard" time allows you to do this at any time within an established link (so long as the link protocol does not timeout during the command session of course).

Comment: The problem is that `pppd` takes over the connection to the serial hardware, so how does one safely pause the PPP traffic and halt the pppd process, take over the serial port, send "(wait)+++(wait)(get OK)AT+CSQ(get response)ATO", and then give back control to `pppd`?

Comment: pppd on Linux may well do that, but is this question about Linux? You  would need to provide support for this at the driver level - through ioctl for example.  The driver would have block or buffer application level data while performing the AT command session.  Maybe Linux already supports that - I am no expert on Linux.

Comment: The question is not necessarily about Linux, although I need to have it work on an embedded system that is running Linux (busybox based) on a microprocessor and LWIP (Light-Weight IP) on a microcontroller.    In this case, I have hardware control over the serial port (below the Linux driver level), so I can manually just cut off the PPP connection and do the AT command, but this will not play nicely with the PPP software.  I was hoping for an approved method of doing this.

Comment: @MarkLakata: I'm sorry - have I missed something here?  This was Linda Lin's question.  What *you need* is not really an issue in this context.  If you have sufficient buffering, stalling the PPP stream for a brief period is not likely to cause any problem whatsoever. While in command mode data from the remote station is likely to be discarded, but the higher level protocol should be able to manage that.  You might wish for a different answer, but I don't think there is one if the antique AT command system is the only interface.